# TeamCity server cannot find java (ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, teamcity

Ubuntu 18.04

sudo ./teamcity-server.sh run

```
Java executable of version 1.8 is not found:
- Java executable is not found under the specified directories: '', '/home/alex/TeamCity/bin/../jre'
- Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
- Java executable is not found in the default locations
- Java executable is not found in the directories listed in the PATH environment variable

Please make sure either JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME environment variable is defined and is pointing to the root directory of the valid Java (JRE) installation

Environment variable FJ_DEBUG can be set to enable debug output

Java not found. Cannot start TeamCity server. Please ensure JDK or JRE is installed and JAVA_HOME environment variable points to it.
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)
alex@teamcity-server:~/TeamCity/bin$
```

$JAVA_HOME (tried default-java, /bin)

```
-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64: Is a directory
```

$JRE_HOME (tried default-java, /bin)

```
-bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64: Is a directory
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

readlink -f $(which java)

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Tried

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin /home/alex/TeamCity/jre
```

Is it requires SPECIFIC java version and does not work with latest?

Did i set variables incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess*, TeamCity is expecting a Java 1.8

> Java executable of version 1.8 is not found.

But you are feeding it with a Java 10

> openjdk version "10.0.2"

The I think the answer to

> Is it requires SPECIFIC java version and does not work with latest?

is "Yes.", it requires Java 1.8 only, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You run server under sudo. Set `$JAVA_HOME` for root too - I guess, it set only for your user.

Comment: Running TeamCity as root (applies to most other pieces of software) is not recommended.